# How to filter multiple data within a single API path?

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter

I have following controller

**MyController.java**

```java
 @GetMapping("/checklessthan")
    public Page<User> demo(@Param(value = "age") String age,
                                                @Param(value ="page") int page,
                                                @Param(value = "size") int size){

        Pageable requestedPage = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        Page<User> user= userRepository.findAllByageLessThan(age, requestedPage);
        return user;
    }

@GetMapping("/checkgreaterthan")
    public Page<User> demo(@Param(value = "age") String age,
                                                @Param(value ="page") int page,
                                                @Param(value = "size") int size){

        Pageable requestedPage = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        Page<User> user= userRepository.findAllByageGreaterThan(age,requestedPage);
        return user;
    }

@GetMapping("/checkEquals")
    public Page<User> demo(@Param(value = "age") String age,
                                                @Param(value ="page") int page,
                                                @Param(value = "size") int size){

        Pageable requestedPage = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        Page<User> user= userRepository.findAllByageEquals(age, requestedPage);
        return user;
    }
```

above 3 APIs is to display the age according to it's method like lessThan, greaterThan or equals age. I want to combine all endpoints into single one.

when i only want to filter lessThanAge then result must give me output of only lessThanAge. same way if i want equalsAge than result must return only equalsAge in output.

so How can I combine above 3 APIs into single API?

Comment: Please note that you can replace `@Param(value ="page") int page, @Param(value = "size") int size`with `Pageable pageable`. Then you can remove `Pageable requestedPage = PageRequest.of(page, size);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the whole context about your base database, but I recommend an API like these.

**First option:**

```
/get_users/age=x&operator=y&page=1&size=10
```

where:

- **age** is the value you request
- **operator** is EQUAL,GREATER or LOWER
- sample: `/get_users/age=1&operator=GREATER&page=1&size=10` means you call `checkgreaterthan` the age of 1

**Second option:**

```
/get_users/from_age=x&to_age=y&page=1&size=10
```

where:

- **from_age** is the min value of age
- **to_age** is the max value of age
- sample `/get_users/from_age=0&to_age=10&page=1&size=10` means you call the `checklessthan` with value of 10, or for overview, you'll always call by age-range

And if you can, can you please update the functions from your DBAL `userRepository`